# Is there a simple way to edit / modify a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

Is there an easier way to edit, for example, the alertBody property of an already scheduled UILocalNotification ?

For now, I just cancel the notification and schedule a new one but when the app needs to do this for 3 or more notifications, it takes long time to execute...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the documentation is correct, you can't alter an already scheduled notification. The doc states for `-scheduleLocalNotification:`:

> […] Because the operating system **copies**
>   notification, you may release it once
>   you have scheduled it.

The notification object is copied by the system and not accessible via any (public) method. So there's no other solution than canceling the notification.

Comment: @Ortwin Gentz : Is there any statement in apple developer document, can't alter an already scheduled notification ??

Comment: Doesn't the quoted language ("copied") imply that it can't be altered anymore?

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit it, but you can achieve a similar effect by canceling a notification and scheduling a new one to replace it with the new data.  Use

`- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`