# How to edit a particular scheduled local notification in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple way to edit / modify a UILocalNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842252/is-there-a-simple-way-to-edit-modify-a-uilocalnotification)

I have an app in which I am firing local notifications at particular time intervals by selecting time from date picker.  I have an edit page where I can change the time of the date picker.  This is working fine.

But the problem is I don't know how to edit a scheduled notification.  I want that the time that i have selected through the edit page and saved should get saved in the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the already scheduled Notification and schedule a new one by computing the time left until the cancelled notification was going to be fired.

To cancel a local notification use `cancelLocalNotification:` of the UIApplication instance you can get using `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`

Answer (score 0):

I think ... you could modify the scheduled notification (Instance of UILocalNotification) ...

[Here is from the Apple documentation ..](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Once you have created an instance of UILocalNotification, you schedule
>   it using one of two methods of the UIApplication class:
>   scheduleLocalNotification: or presentLocalNotificationNow:. The former
>   method use the fire date to schedule delivery; the latter method
>   presents the notification immediately, regardless of the value of
>   fireDate. You can cancel specific or all local notifications by
>   calling cancelLocalNotification: or cancelAllLocalNotifications,
>   respectively.

So you can cancel the notification and then schedule it again using 
[scheduleLocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Here is from the Apple documentation ..](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Note: Prior to iOS 4.2, this property was a read-only method. A setter
>   method has been added and the method has been converted to a
>   read-write property. When you set this property, UILocalNotification
>   replaces all existing notifications by calling
>   cancelLocalNotification: and then calling scheduleLocalNotification:
>   for each new notification.

Comment: but i want that when i select time from datepicker which is in different class and click on the save button that time must get saved on my previously scheduled notification