# Random Repeating Local Notifications in Swift

Tags: swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationtrigger

TL;DR: Is it possible to have repeating, random local notifications without using `APNS` (or an alternative push notification service)?

I am building a `Core Data` app that includes a bunch of objects. (We'll call them widgets.) Every day at a certain time – let's say noon – I want to send a notification to check out one of these widgets.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I check to make sure Notifications are enabled and set the delegate, etc. and call a function to build the local notification. All this is working perfectly.

```
    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = 12
    date.minute = 00
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "You should see this widget!"
    content.userInfo = ["widgetID": widget.id]
    content.body = "Today's Widget:\n\(widget.title!)"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifer, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error : Error?) in if let theError = error { print(theError.localizedDescription)}}
```

And I have the delegate's handler working correctly, too:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { ... a bunch of stuff to happen ... }
```

As it is now, in that function I'm able to "reset" the `UNMutableNotificationContent` to a new random widget **IF** the user interacts with the notification in any explicit way.
The problem is that if the user *doesn't* interact with the notification at all — see the "Handling the Standard System Actions" section of Apple's [Scheduling and Handling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) documentation — I have no way to "reset" the notification, so tomorrow they're simply going to get suggested the same widget again, and that's annoying.

I'm not really interested in using `APNS` (or an alternative) because I don't feel like I should need to do that and don't want to deal with all the extra stuff required,  but I cannot seem to find an alternative.

Please note that this question is *not* a duplicate of:

- [Is it possible to update the local notification on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620689/is-it-possible-to-update-the-local-notification-in-iphone)
- [Is there a simple way to edit/modify a UILocalNotification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842252/is-there-a-simple-way-to-edit-modify-a-uilocalnotification)
- [Swift local notification with dynamic alert body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835377/swift-local-notification-with-dynamic-alert-body)
- [How to update body of repeated local notification in iOs 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507657/how-to-update-body-of-repeated-local-notification-in-ios-10)
- [IOS Overriding Local Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768568/ios-overriding-local-notifications)

Comment: Instead of scheduling the local notification to repeat itself, you might schedule it only once the first time and then every time the user interacts with the popup.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Right. As I explained, though, that's what I'm doing now. The problem is if the user ignores or swipes to dismiss the alert, they are simply going to receive the same alert the next day.

Comment: You say: "they are simply going to receive the same alert the next day". If you avoid the repeat it (`repeats: false`), why should it be there the next day?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I *want* the notification to repeat every day; But I also want the content included in the widget to be different every day.

Comment: @DavidVincentGagne did you ever get this system working or have you ended up going another route? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Simon: No, I never really got an answer here. But I realized that if the user does not interact with the notification at all, the fact that it's the same the next day doesn't matter in my use case.

Comment: @DavidVincentGagne thanks for the answer after all this time since your comment, I actually made my piece with that also in the meantime. Thanks again!

Comment: has anyone worked out how to create dynamic content for location notifications yet?