# one signal notification inactive message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, push-notification, onesignal

I want to make a push notification that is triggered when the user hasn't logged in to the game. I would like to send the message `You haven't login "dynamic value" day` to the user. I think I can use offline notifications to do that. But I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

PS: I use the Unity to integrate the one signal.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.LocalNotification.html
for IOS , Unity Have local notification API in IOS , You can watch this.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/simple-android-notifications-free-68626
For Android , Unity Not Souport , But You can download plugin for free , check this link.

Comment: hello, do you know that one signal can support it or not?

Comment: I know that the limit of local notifications is 64 , And I Think you can make a schedule that it repeat in one notification ,
But I dont know how to set  "dynamic value" in notification , I think maybe can not to do that.

Comment: Hello, If I use LocalNotification method, how can I send the message every day

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.LocalNotification-repeatInterval.html
IOS look this link , that paramter can setting how long repeat once,
Android Plugin Also Have , This Plugin have demo

Comment: Hello, I can't find any repeat method or variable in Android Plugin.  Can you specfic which method do I need?

Comment: In NotificationExample.cs , Method Name ScheduleRepeated()

Comment: I think that method is pay version.

Comment: I need to implement the function about if some users haven't login 1 days. It will send `you haven't login 1 day`. If 2 days will set to 2 days. How to send a notification with dynamic value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835377/swift-local-notification-with-dynamic-alert-body?rq=1

You are not make a local notification with dynamic value , because local notification is in background schedule, not in your APP , Maybe your App not running in that moment, So you can't calculation a value when you get it.