# Override an already displayed Local Notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

How I can override an already displayed Local Notification?

I just want one notification for a particular event where the value is changing from time to time, when a change for the event appear.

For the moment there is always a new notification created.

Comment: Notifications that has been already displayed cannot be modified.

Comment: I assume you mean to change an already scheduled notification, right?

Comment: Yes but the notification should not be really scheduled. I want to have something like that: App is in background mode, there is something happening --> Notification on screen, now maybe 10 seconds after or 5 seconds after or X -seconds after there will be a changed for the same event X-seconds before. Now I want to change this notification from before, without displaying a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the documentation is correct, you can't alter an already scheduled notification. The doc states for `-scheduleLocalNotification:`:

> […] Because the operating system copies notification, you may release
>   it once you have scheduled it. The notification object is copied by
>   the system and not accessible via any (public) method. So there's no
>   other solution than canceling the notification.

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842252/is-there-a-simple-way-to-edit-modify-a-uilocalnotification)

Comment: Thanks. So this sounds I should cancel the notification before I create the same one just with an updated text.